# how to create custom ObjectChoiceField with full screen width and label on top

Tags: blackberry

I'm new in developing with the Java BlackBerry SDK.

I want to create a custom `ObjectChoiceField` with full screen width and the label placed on top-left of it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a *hack*, but you can accomplish this by:

1. Adding space to the choices (Strings) in your `ObjectChoiceField`, in order to space them out to full-screen width.
2. Simply add a separate `LabelField` to a manager **above** the custom `ObjectChoiceField`.

Like this:

```java
   public class FullWidthChoiceField extends ObjectChoiceField {

      private Object[] _choices;  // cached for convenience
      private int _orientation;   // track device orientation

      public void setChoices(Object[] choices) {
         // TODO: this pixel value may need some tweaking!
         final int HBUFFER_PX = 62;
         int desiredWidth = Display.getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()
               - getMarginLeft() - getMarginRight() - HBUFFER_PX;
         Font font = getFont();         
         int advanceOfOneSpace = font.getAdvance(' ');

         for (int c = 0; c < choices.length; c++) {  
            String trimmedChoice = ((String)choices[c]).trim();
            // how wide is the text for this choice?          
            int advance = font.getAdvance(trimmedChoice);
            int numSpacesToPad = Math.max(0, (desiredWidth - advance) / advanceOfOneSpace);
            char[] pad = new char[numSpacesToPad];
            Arrays.fill(pad, ' ');
            choices[c] = new String(pad) + trimmedChoice;  // pad to left of choice
         }

         _choices = choices;
         super.setChoices(choices);
      }

      // only needed if your app supports rotation!
      protected void layout(int width, int height) {
         super.layout(width, height);
         if (_orientation != Display.getOrientation()) {
            // orientation change -> we must readjust the choice field
            _orientation = Display.getOrientation();
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                  setChoices(_choices);               
               }
            });
         }
      }           
   }
```

And use it in a `Screen` like this:

```java
   public ObjectChoiceScreen() {
      super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);

      Object[] choices = new Object[] { "one", "two", "three" };
      ObjectChoiceField ocf = new FullWidthChoiceField();
      ocf.setChoices(choices);

      VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();
      vfm.add(new LabelField("Label", Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH));  //  | DrawStyle.HCENTER));
      vfm.add(ocf);
      add(vfm);
   }
```

Resulting in

[image]

This requires that you set the field's choices by calling `ocf.setChoices()` and not in the constructor.  You can certainly add that to a custom constructor if you like.

Comment: thanks Nate, I just implemented it, and it work, great thanks :D